# How to rationalize $(\sqrt{4 + h} - 2) / h$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, rationalising-denominator

> How to rationalize this? 
>   $$\frac{\sqrt{4 + h} - 2} h$$

I tried multiplying it by $$\frac{\sqrt{4 + h} + 2}{\sqrt{4 + h} + 2}$$  but I could not get the correct answer.

The correct answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 + h} + 2}$.

Comment: I've edited your post to (hopefully) fix the formulas. Please make sure it says what you intend.

Comment: Technically, that formula is already "rationalized," in that there are no square roots in the denominator,

Answer (score 1):

When you foil out $(\sqrt{4+h}-2)(\sqrt{4+h}+2)$ the "inner and outer" terms cancel and you have $4+h-4=h.$

So after the division by $h$ in the given expression it becomes the answer you quote.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right, I didn't notice the  $h$ in the denominator of the original. I'll just erase the second half.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't rationalizing usually go in the reverse direction? Anyway, you get from point a to point b as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+h}+2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+h}+2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}{\sqrt{4+h}-2}=\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}{h}
$$